# How to initialise a pointer member in a struct type inline?

Tags: go

With a type:

```
type A struct {
   B int, C *int
}
```

How do I initialise a pointer member to a non-zero value inline, without creating temporaries?

```
a := A{
    B: 42,
    C: ?,
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about "creating temporaries" -- Go is garbage collected so a struct will be temporary (i.e. get garbage-collected) if possible, or it will stick around if something references it. The GC takes care of that for you.

Comment: @MatrixFrog I don't care about the GC, but readability of the code.

Comment: Quite contrived and not super readable, but a nice trick: `p := &([]int{42}[0])` initializes `p` to be a pointer to 42. The even less readable `p := func(i int) *int {return &i}()` works as well (but you can factor it out as James Henstridge suggests)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the specific example you've given you are limited in what you can do without introducing additional statements.

If you want `C` to point at an initialised integer variable, you will need an additional statement to define that variable since you can't take the address of an integer literal (i.e. `&42` would be an error).

If you just want to initialise `C` as a pointer to a new zero value, you are in luck though and can set it to `new(int)`.

If you were instead dealing with a different type that had an initialiser syntax, you would also been in luck.  For example, if `C` was a pointer to a structure, you could initialise it to `&TheStruct{...}`.

If none of these are appropriate, and you are really only after code clarity for initialising `*int` variables, a helper function might fit your requirements.  For example:

```
func makeIntPointer(v int) *int {
    return &v
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    B int 
    C *int
}

func newint(i int) *int{
    return &i
}

func main() {
    c := newint(5)
    a := &A{
            B: 42,
            C: c,
         }

    fmt.Printf(" %v" , *a.C)
    fmt.Printf(" %#v" , a.C)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/s0HIMHoMRo

Comment: Exactly what I would do. http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals